# How to remove a keybind after it has done its job

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, key-bindings

I created a keybind, and want to delete it after it is activated. How do I do this?

I have tried this in my code:

```
def testing(event):
    print("Hello!")

root.bind_all('<Key>', testing)
root.deletecommand('<Key>', testing)
```

However, this does not work, as Python displays an error message stating that `deletecommand() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`, when I only gave two arguments. I also tried `root.delete('<Key>', testing)`, but this also fails.

```
from tkinter import *

def testing(event):
    print("Hello!")

root.bind_all('<Key>', testing)
root.deletecommand('<Key>', testing)

root.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I was hoping that the program would remove the keybind after it did its job. However, Python displayed an error message, as mentioned before. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Isn't it just `root.unbind('<Key>')` and not `root.deletecommand(...)`?

Comment: Although there is no error with this, the `root.unbind` command does not remove the keybind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try as this

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()


def testing(event):
    print("Hello!")
    root.unbind_all('<Key>')


root.bind_all('<Key>', testing)
root.mainloop()
```

For unbind all the widget use the function `.unbind_all('<Key>')`.

Comment: In this game (the code I provided is only an excerpt), I have "Press any key to continue." How do I remove it after the player presses a key?

Comment: i think that the best way is do this: for first apply the `.bind_all('<Key>',  function)` method at the root and after inside the `function` that you want to call when the user presses any key apply at the `root` the `.unbind_all('<Key>')` method

Comment: So how do I remove the "Press any key to continue" label when the player presses a key?

Comment: You can do this in two ways: 1) you you write in the function that you call when the player presses any key that it has to destroy the label so you put in the function something like this `.unbind_all('<Key>')` and `Press_any_key_label.destroy()`. 2) you create the binding on other events `.bind("<KeyPress>", function)` that call a function when the player presses any key and the the second bind `.bind("<KeyRelease>", function2)` that do something when the playere releases the key that he pressed. i think it would be better the first option, is simpler.